# Could not load file or assemble 'System.Data.SqlClient Version 0.0.0.0 in UNIT test with interface mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

Creating unit test for simple class method. Class structure is

```
public class GenericRepository<T>:ILogRepository,IGenericRepository<T> where T:class
{
    private ICoreDb _coreDb = null;
    private Logger _logger = null;

 public GenericRepository(string connectionName)
    {
        _coreDb = new Coredb(connectionName);
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public GenericRepository(ICoreDb coreDb)
    {
        _coreDb = coreDb;
    }

    
    public string ConvertByteArrayToFileAndSave(byte[] excel,string filePath)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, excel);
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

And Coredb.cs is

```
public  class Coredb : ICoreDb
{
    private string _connectionString{get;set;}
    private Logger _logger { get; set; }
    public Coredb()
    {
        _connectionString = null;
    }
   
    public Coredb(string connectionName)
    {
        _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
        _connectionString = _connectionString.Replace("YY", "user").Replace("ZZZZZZZZ", @"password");
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(connectionName + "-CoreDb:UploadExcel.Repository");
    }
  }
```

And my unittest is

```
Mock<UploadExcel.Repository.ICoreDb> _coreDb = new Mock<UploadExcel.Repository.ICoreDb>();;
```

arrange work is

```
  UploadExcel.Repository.GenericRepository.GenericRepository
  <UploadExcel.EntityRepository.MR.MREntity> repository =
                                            new 
  UploadExcel.Repository.GenericRepository.GenericRepository
                             <UploadExcel.EntityRepository.MR.MREntity> 
  (_coreDb.Object);
        resultFilePath = repository.ConvertByteArrayToFileAndSave(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath), 
  ResultFilePath);
```

During arrange work in unittesting i am not able to create object of
Generic class type. I thought this was due to parameterized construcor in coredb class file but then i added default consturctor as well , even then i am getting this error. Please suggest some solution.

```
Message: 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, 
Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the 
file specified.
```

Please help.

Comment: What is your connection string?  Does connection string use LocalDb?  Error message is indicating that the System.Data.SqlClient (a dll) is running and can't find the database specified by the connection string.

Comment: I have tried adding connection string code lines of parameterized constructor into default constructor as well, but still getting same error.`public Coredb()
    {
        _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
        _connectionString = _connectionString.Replace("YY", "user").Replace("ZZZZZZZZ", @"password");
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(connectionName + "-CoreDb:UploadExcel.Repository");
    }`'

Comment: What is actual connection string (you can x out the username and password?  Need to see actual string.  Are you using Excel or SQL Server (SQLClient)?  Is database mounted to SQL Server or is a LocalDb?  Is database using Windows credentials or SQL Server credentials?

Comment: This is connection string in web.config      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=0.0.0.0,1232;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=YY;Password=ZZZZZZZZ"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: The Data source has to be the name or IP or the server.  Not 0.0.0.0.  I would us SQL Server Management Studio to log onto database.  The login window has two options 1) Window Credentials 2) sql Server.  Try each and see if you can access the database.  Windows Credentials does now require a password and uses the user login credentials.

Comment: dude these are dummy values.

Comment: Did you try like I suggested and use SQL Server Management Studio to check the connection method and credentials?

Comment: Problem solved. Sql.Data.SqlClient reference was not added in Test project. After adding it's working.